# Can we start from the restriction, and continue with the normal function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, field-theory

Suppose that we have the field automorphism $\phi :C\rightarrow C$ with $\phi (a)=b$.

When we consider the restriction $\phi|_K :K\rightarrow C$, and we have that $a^n\in K$, do we have the following? 
$$\phi|_K (a^n)=\phi|_K (a\cdot a \cdot \ldots \cdot a)=\phi (a)\cdot \phi (a)\cdot \ldots \cdot \phi (a)=b\cdot b\cdot \ldots \cdot b=b^n\in K$$

Or can we not start from the restriction at K, and continue with the normal function $\phi$ ?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The only thing restriction does is change the domain, it doesn't change where the points in the domain are mapped.

Comment: Ah I think I missed something in my question. We have the finite extension $F\leq K\leq E$, where $K/F$ is normal. Having the field $F$-automorphism $\phi :C\rightarrow C$, then $\phi|_K :K\rightarrow C$ is a $F$-monomorphism. Then by a theorem of normal extensions it follows that $\phi|_K :K\rightarrow K$ is an automorphism, right? So, does it follow from that that $b^n\in K$ ? @tomasz

Comment: what do you mean it is an $F$-monomorfism?

Comment: That's really confusing. You should put a clear statement of the question in its body.

Comment: This means that $\phi$ is a monomorphism and it holds that $\phi (f)=f, \forall f\in F$. @JorgeFernándezHidalgo

Comment: $\phi(f)=f$ or $\phi(f)\in F$?

Comment: $\phi(f)=f$ @JorgeFernándezHidalgo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the equalities that you wrote are true except the last one. We do not necessarily have $b^n\in K$.

Comment: Ah I think I missed something in my question. We have the finite extension $F\leq K\leq E$, where $K/F$ is normal. Having the field $F$-automorphism $\phi :C\rightarrow C$, then $\phi|_K :K\rightarrow C$ is a $F$-monomorphism. Then by a theorem of normal extensions it follows that $\phi|_K :K\rightarrow K$ is an automorphism, right? So, does it follow from that that $b^n\in K$ ?

Comment: So, now it follows that $b^n\in K$, or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiarized with that result, but if that result is true then you are correct.

Comment: Ok. Thanks!! :-)